# How to parse country code from RFC 5646 locale string?

Tags: locale, country-codes

The [`GetUserDefaultLocaleName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnls/nf-winnls-getuserdefaultlocalename) Win32 API returns a locale name string based on [RFC 5646](https://www.rfc-editor.org/info/rfc5646).  How can I retrieve the country code from this string?

The format doesn't have an obvious way to do this, because it has a variable number of entries.  For example, Latin-script Uzbek in Uzbekistan is `uz-Latn-UZ`.  Given that entries can also appear after the country code, how would I know which part is the country code?